# Encrypt numeric URL parameter, result should not be longer than original

Tags: php, url, encryption

I have to encrypt a particular URL parameter. If I want the output to be below 6-7 characters, what algorithm should I use?

The inputs are integer only ranging from 1 to 1,000,000.

Comment: since 1 million is 7 chars, why do you need to encode?

Comment: i dont want it to be in clear text. this is actually a requirement

Comment: What are your security concerns ? If you only need to obfuscate you could convert your number into another numerical base using `base_convert`.

Comment: Ok, not clear text, but is it also required that a user not be able to decode it?

Comment: I was using mcrypt_blowfish with a salt. This kind of solved all the problems but the person now wants the encoded string to be very small. @Bathz I need some security

Comment: @SNAG — What sort of security? From whom are you trying to hide this string? What is the specific use case?

Comment: @Repox not homework I am selling a particular product and the buyer needs some cosmetic changes

Comment: @Quentin I have no idea why the buyer wants it to be encrypted. Is there anyway for getting such a short encoded output

Comment: @SNAG — You need to know what the problem is because you can solve it. It is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where Y hasn't been clearly described in the first place. (Frankly, plain ASCII would give you a short encoding, but it sounds like that won't match up to the description of Y).

Comment: @SNAG Check answer, 4 to 12 chars depending on input.

Comment: @SNAG Made my answer within the specified range.

Comment: updated my answer to use encryption and url-safe representation and still producing strings within the specified length range.

Comment: thanks for the help @matthew. convinced the guy that 12 characters is the best that can be achieved.

Comment: @SNAG actually, its not. see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you require encryption and need to have the shortest result possible, you must use a stream cipher. Blowfish (what you previously used) is a blockcipher and the result will always have the minimum size of one single block.

Find a [comparison of stream ciphers on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher#Comparison_Of_Stream_Ciphers) and the list of supported ciphers in the [PHP manual on mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php)

Also, the result of the encryption may contain special chars, so when putting it into an URL as a parameter, you should use `urlencode()` or `base64_encode()`

Using `urlencode()` or `base64_encode()` will expand your string, making it longer than the original data. This is necessary to make it transport/URL safe.

However, since your input is always a number you can use `base_convert()` to shorten your input. On the decoding side, you'd have to do reverse the same thing.

To get *even shorter results*, you could make use of the [`enminicode()` / `deminicode()` function provided by Aron Cederholm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391416/43959) instead of using `base_convert()`.

Here is an example using the RC4 stream cipher (which is not very strong, by the way) and conversion from base 10 to base 36.

**NOTE:** this example only works on numbers hence its using `base_convert()` to shrink the input string!

```
function my_number_encrypt($data, $key, $base64_safe=true, $shrink=true) {
        if ($shrink) $data = base_convert($data, 10, 36);
        $data = @mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM);
        if ($base64_safe) $data = str_replace('=', '', base64_encode($data));
        return $data;
}

function my_number_decrypt($data, $key, $base64_safe=true, $expand=true) {
        if ($base64_safe) $data = base64_decode($data.'==');
        $data = @mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM);
        if ($expand) $data = base_convert($data, 36, 10);
        return $data;
}

$data = "15231223";
$key = "&/ASD%g/..&FWSF2csvsq2we!%%";

echo "data: ", $data, "\n";
$encrypted = my_number_encrypt($data, $key);
echo "encrypted: ", $encrypted, "\n";
$decrypted = my_number_decrypt($encrypted, $key);
echo "decrypted: ", $decrypted, "\n";
```

Result:

```
data: 15231223
encrypted: BuF3xdE
decrypted: 15231223
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple convert it to hexadecimal.

```
$number= 1000000;
echo base_convert($number, 10, 16); // f4240
```

You want even have fun and convert it to a base 36

```
$number= 1000000;
echo base_convert($number, 10, 36);
```

And do the reverse operation to decode :

```
$base46_number = 'LFLS';
$decimal = base_convert($base46_number, 36, 10);
```

Comment: PHP docs for base_convert() say `both frombase and tobase have to be between 2 and 36, inclusive` .. so it's not safe to assume base 46 will always work, even though it does in current PHP versions.

Answer (score 3):

```
function enminicode($int) {
    $foo = '';
    while ($int) {
        $tmp =  $int%256;
        $int = floor($int/256);
        $foo = chr($tmp) . $foo;
    }
    return base64_encode($foo);
}

function deminicode($b64) {
    $moo = base64_decode($b64);
    $res = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($moo) - 1; ++$i) {
        $res *= 256;
        $res += ord($moo[$i]);
    }
    return $res;
}

$ii = array(12, 123456, 1000000, 467, 9456724645);
foreach ($ii as $i) {
    echo $i, ': ', enminicode($i), ' => ', deminicode(enminicode($i)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
12: DA== => 12
123456: AeJA => 123456
1000000: D0JA => 1000000
467: AdM= => 467
9456724645: AjOqKqU= => 9456724645
```

Works like a charm. For integers up to 1000000 it will consume 4 letters. But do not use this for security! Security by obscurity is never an option, and you never try this method to hide a number from the user if they are not meant to know about it.

Another more elegant solution is to use base_convert, which will yield slightly longer strings, but it will still fit within 6-7 characters.

```
$int = 987654;
$convert = base_convert($int, 10, 16)
$original = base_convert($convert, 16, 10)
echo $convert, PHP_EOL; #f1206
echo $original, PHP_EOL; #987654
```

output:

```
f1206
987654
```

Comment: looks very obscure and complex, compared to other solutions.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is. Hence the second proposed solution. But the solution proposed by Iceduck is even better, with base_convert($int, 10, 46)

Comment: nevertheless, very elegant solution. +1 for binary stuff